# Dynamic use of material icons

Tags: typescript, next.js, material-ui

I making a web app that let user create categories. Each category can have any icon from material UI. Icons are saved as string in the db. I was wondering how I can display the icons without loading all icons. I'm currently dynamically loading icons like this

```js
export const dynamicComponents: DynamicComponents = {
  Abc: dynamic(() => import("@mui/icons-material/Abc"), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
  }) as DynamicIconType,
  MoreHoriz: dynamic(() => import("@mui/icons-material/MoreHoriz"), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
  }) as DynamicIconType,
}
```

But I was wondering if there was an other way to do it?

I don't want to load all icons for bundle size.